# How can I use the WSDL web service in PHP?

Tags: php, soap, webserver

I want to use site [tsetmc.com](http://service.tsetmc.com/WebService/TsePublicV2.asmx?WSDL) web service in my robot but I don't know exactly how to do it
Code web service:

```
<s:element name="Company">
        <s:complexType>
          <s:sequence>
            <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="UserName" type="s:string" />
            <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Password" type="s:string" />
            <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Flow" type="s:unsignedByte" />
          </s:sequence>
        </s:complexType>
      </s:element>
      <s:element name="CompanyResponse">
        <s:complexType>
          <s:sequence>
            <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="CompanyResult">
              <s:complexType>
                <s:sequence>
                  <s:element ref="s:schema" />
                  <s:any />
                </s:sequence>
              </s:complexType>
            </s:element>
          </s:sequence>
        </s:complexType>
      </s:element>
```

---

```
    $client = new SoapClient("http://service.tsetmc.com/WebService/TsePublicV2.asmx?WSDL", array('soap_version'   => SOAP_1_2));
echo'<pre>';
var_dump($client->__getFunctions());
var_dump($client->__getTypes());
echo'</pre>';
echo'<hr>';
$params = array(
    "UserName" => "--",
    "Password" => "---",
    "Flow" => 0,
);
$response = $client->__soapCall("Company", array($params));
if($response)
{
    echo 'true <br>';
    var_dump($response);
}else{
    echo 'false';
}
```

The following operations are supported. For a formal definition, please review the [Service Description.](http://service.tsetmc.com/webservice/TsePublicV2.asmx)

Company service name
[help web service](http://cdn.tsetmc.com/Site.aspx?ParTree=11141111)

Please guide me to use this web service

Thanks

Comment: **Result** `object(stdClass)#2 (0) { }`